# Does building farms destroy strategic resources?

Tags: civilization-6

I am afraid to build farms or other improvements because I think I might accidentally replace a late game strategic resource like Uranium before it pops on the map.

Is it a valid reason to be worried about or does the game handle it some other way?

Comment: The Civilization II engineer *unit* actually had the ability to change terrain types, from e.g. hills to plains. This would destroy the resource that was on the tile, if I recall. Civ IV and onwards only had engineers as specialist citizens, so resource modification/destruction hasn't been a factor in a long time.

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/289301/20005

Comment: Placing city and wonders (also districts in civ6) does not destroy resources I am aware about that. I was wondering about farms and mines.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Since resources *are* predetermined when the map is created, the game won't look at what gets built there before revealing a strategic resource later in the game; because that is what happens, they are *revealed*.

That being said, **no your farms will not replace the resource, nor will any other builder improvement**. Say you build a farm on a hill, and then uranium is revealed there. You can easily replace the farm by building the appropriate mine right over top.

As a bonus piece of info, [noted here](https://www.reddit.com/r/civ/comments/57vak8/questionciv_vi_does_founding_a_city_on_luxury/) and from my own experience, building a city over top that resource will not remove it either. So if you happen to build on top of coal, uranium etc, later in the game you will just receive it for free - no improvement needed.

Comment: It's so disappointing how the game ignores the *benefits* of uranium-fueled food in your population's diet...

Comment: Minor extension: what you said about cities also applies to districts; provided that the district was plopped down (not necessarily fully built) _before_ the resource was revealed.

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 1):

You're fine. The resource will still be there when it's revealed, and you can simply build another type of construction to gather that resource more efficiently

Comment: You don't begin to "gather" a resource more "efficiently", you just are able to own it with the appropriate improvement.

Comment: You can build some constructions which give you more of the resource if they're worked

Comment: An example being? I don't know of constructions that improve the amount of resource you get from *strategic* resources.

Comment: You can assign workers (specialists) to them, in some cases

Comment: In what cases in specific? I've never heard of that.